# acutality of building tags fetched by osmnx

Tags: osmnx

Can one say something to the actuality of buildings and its tags?  
E.g. I fetch https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/557584181 via OSMNX and it says building=construction but on OSM it says building=office. I see it was edited about 1 month ago.

Unfortunately I am using OMSNX v. 0.9 due to I am working with other packages that limit me to pandas=0.23.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I guess it was cached somewhere.

```
import osmnx as ox
from shapely import geometry

type(given_geo_area)
```

> shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon

```
print(given_geo_area)
```

> POLYGON ((9.444757321553571 47.6640820372137, 9.44469147049122 47.6642370363376, 9.442746638836271 47.6675223477341, 9.44273323863089 47.6675486765942, 9.44272335456083 47.6675846924473, 9.44272337322715 47.6675856076278, 9.44272365679015 47.667586502615, 9.442724194246059 47.6675873426787, 9.442724964738851 47.6675880952201, 9.442725938369239 47.6675887310364, 9.442771524985689 47.6676085195463, 9.442809078141879 47.6676199425426, 9.443599054706221 47.6678292167847, 9.44364298889086 47.6678391758214, 9.44369319196211 47.6678454078942, 9.443694609235431 47.6678454056071, 9.44369600193242 47.6678452280573, 9.443697323077419 47.6678448812336, 9.443698528108349 47.6678443768344, 9.443744598701199 47.6678160313241, 9.443795360184319 47.6677784822092, 9.443991191770809 47.6676599114601, 9.44421793991903 47.667570002951, 9.44446657647225 47.667512336406, 9.44472720190474 47.6674892078198, 9.444989439424219 47.6675015380556, 9.445052589744799 47.6675088406224, 9.445117064489731 47.6675174206873, 9.445183601261711 47.6675274468952, 9.44523747329856 47.6675300193568, 9.445238809309229 47.6675299032106, 9.4452400852424 47.6675296113077, 9.445241251079061 47.667529155091, 9.445242261116221 47.6675285524453, 9.445243075758549 47.6675278269953, 9.44524366307046 47.6675270071801, 9.445257172339209 47.6674916444378, 9.44526138400154 47.6674643786881, 9.44526635876986 47.6674027181877, 9.44527842375639 47.6673216144847, 9.44528702520314 47.6672820624034, 9.445343690252869 47.6671237851091, 9.44544200701166 47.6669751340207, 9.445578690330031 47.6668410756375, 9.445606929899901 47.666818179473, 9.445637520256669 47.6667867600046, 9.445694232828229 47.6667392820943, 9.445718033000571 47.6667110812337, 9.445816550854619 47.6665782840333, 9.445885789521761 47.6664961432372, 9.44592142419992 47.6664586450851, 9.44609642847751 47.6663115101204, 9.446313359526091 47.6661926345661, 9.44656247099808 47.6661073591621, 9.4468325709589 47.6660595150674, 9.447111524661491 47.6660512517601, 9.44717730910928 47.6660540322315, 9.447316189895529 47.6660649297759, 9.44753610831893 47.6660902456686, 9.44758112940486 47.6660938580278, 9.44767071891042 47.6660918313842, 9.447684852061499 47.6660900296329, 9.44774691292624 47.6660795923001, 9.4479881800759 47.6660547725018, 9.448232085468209 47.6660604809193, 9.448470258112661 47.6660965216365, 9.448560914386359 47.6661163562617, 9.44857404167368 47.6661182063231, 9.448691583060739 47.6661430580836, 9.44873711713312 47.6661476818212, 9.44936429835351 47.6661892570172, 9.44940607834077 47.66619064719, 9.44946122599818 47.6661870380657, 9.449463401923399 47.6661858503929, 9.449498075077059 47.6661578721339, 9.449520006942709 47.6661337837734, 9.45042894326825 47.6650175089795, 9.45044714891934 47.6649921250378, 9.450463499380801 47.6649559172176, 9.450463614247271 47.6649550512483, 9.450463463599689 47.664954187754, 9.450463053866351 47.6649533635807, 9.45046240253088 47.6649526138965, 9.450461537386341 47.6649519706911, 9.450460495349169 47.6649514614106, 9.45040935260457 47.6649360626301, 9.45036907619812 47.664928709451, 9.447377834868041 47.6644933952575, 9.447343269935271 47.6644880343118, 9.44730847614896 47.6644823034133, 9.44727413690042 47.6644763151236, 9.444928887305879 47.6640444576946, 9.444886220360861 47.6640381906818, 9.444829205115131 47.6640359557828, 9.4448279422305 47.6640360849357, 9.44482674602855 47.6640363876611, 9.44482566804831 47.6640368509158, 9.444757321553571 47.6640820372137))

```
buildings = ox.footprints_from_polygon(given_geo_area)


buildings.loc[buildings.index == 557584181]['building']
```

> > 557584181    construction
> > Name: building, dtype: object

Edit2:

Now I tried to provide a reproducible code like:

```
import osmnx as ox
from shapely import geometry


area = [
    geometry.Point(9.444757321553571, 47.6640820372137), 
    geometry.Point(9.44469147049122, 47.6642370363376), 
    geometry.Point(9.442746638836271, 47.6675223477341),
    geometry.Point(9.44273323863089, 47.6675486765942),
    geometry.Point(9.44272335456083, 47.6675846924473),
    geometry.Point(9.44272337322715, 47.6675856076278),
    geometry.Point(9.44272365679015, 47.667586502615),
    geometry.Point(9.442724194246059, 47.6675873426787),
    geometry.Point(9.442724964738851, 47.6675880952201),
    geometry.Point(9.442725938369239, 47.6675887310364),
    geometry.Point(9.442771524985689, 47.6676085195463),
    geometry.Point(9.442809078141879, 47.6676199425426),
    geometry.Point(9.443599054706221, 47.6678292167847),
    geometry.Point(9.44364298889086, 47.6678391758214),
    geometry.Point(9.44369319196211, 47.6678454078942),
    geometry.Point(9.443694609235431, 47.6678454056071),
    geometry.Point(9.44369600193242, 47.6678452280573),
    geometry.Point(9.443697323077419, 47.6678448812336),
    geometry.Point(9.443698528108349, 47.6678443768344),
    geometry.Point(9.443744598701199, 47.6678160313241),
    geometry.Point(9.443795360184319, 47.6677784822092),
    geometry.Point(9.443991191770809, 47.6676599114601),
    geometry.Point(9.44421793991903, 47.667570002951),
    geometry.Point(9.44446657647225, 47.667512336406),
    geometry.Point(9.44472720190474, 47.6674892078198),
    geometry.Point(9.444989439424219, 47.6675015380556),
    geometry.Point(9.445052589744799, 47.6675088406224),
    geometry.Point(9.445117064489731, 47.6675174206873),
    geometry.Point(9.445183601261711, 47.6675274468952),
    geometry.Point(9.44523747329856, 47.6675300193568),
    geometry.Point(9.445238809309229, 47.6675299032106),
    geometry.Point(9.4452400852424, 47.6675296113077),
    geometry.Point(9.445241251079061, 47.667529155091),
    geometry.Point(9.445242261116221, 47.6675285524453),
    geometry.Point(9.445243075758549, 47.6675278269953),
    geometry.Point(9.44524366307046, 47.6675270071801),
    geometry.Point(9.445257172339209, 47.6674916444378),
    geometry.Point(9.44526138400154, 47.6674643786881),
    geometry.Point(9.44526635876986, 47.6674027181877),
    geometry.Point(9.44527842375639, 47.6673216144847),
    geometry.Point(9.44528702520314, 47.6672820624034),
    geometry.Point(9.445343690252869, 47.6671237851091),
    geometry.Point(9.44544200701166, 47.6669751340207),
    geometry.Point(9.445578690330031, 47.6668410756375),
    geometry.Point(9.445606929899901, 47.666818179473),
    geometry.Point(9.445637520256669, 47.6667867600046),
    geometry.Point(9.445694232828229, 47.6667392820943),
    geometry.Point(9.445718033000571, 47.6667110812337),
    geometry.Point(9.445816550854619, 47.6665782840333),
    geometry.Point(9.445885789521761, 47.6664961432372),
    geometry.Point(9.44592142419992, 47.6664586450851),
    geometry.Point(9.44609642847751, 47.6663115101204),
    geometry.Point(9.446313359526091, 47.6661926345661),
    geometry.Point(9.44656247099808, 47.6661073591621),
    geometry.Point(9.4468325709589, 47.6660595150674),
    geometry.Point(9.447111524661491, 47.6660512517601),
    geometry.Point(9.44717730910928, 47.6660540322315),
    geometry.Point(9.447316189895529, 47.6660649297759),
    geometry.Point(9.44753610831893, 47.6660902456686),
    geometry.Point(9.44758112940486, 47.6660938580278),
    geometry.Point(9.44767071891042, 47.6660918313842),
    geometry.Point(9.447684852061499, 47.6660900296329),
    geometry.Point(9.44774691292624, 47.6660795923001),
    geometry.Point(9.4479881800759, 47.6660547725018),
    geometry.Point(9.448232085468209, 47.6660604809193),
    geometry.Point(9.448470258112661, 47.6660965216365),
    geometry.Point(9.448560914386359, 47.6661163562617),
    geometry.Point(9.44857404167368, 47.6661182063231),
    geometry.Point(9.448691583060739, 47.6661430580836),
    geometry.Point(9.44873711713312, 47.6661476818212),
    geometry.Point(9.44936429835351, 47.6661892570172),
    geometry.Point(9.44940607834077, 47.66619064719),
    geometry.Point(9.44946122599818, 47.6661870380657),
    geometry.Point(9.449463401923399, 47.6661858503929),
    geometry.Point(9.449498075077059, 47.6661578721339),
    geometry.Point(9.449520006942709, 47.6661337837734),
    geometry.Point(9.45042894326825, 47.6650175089795),
    geometry.Point(9.45044714891934, 47.6649921250378),
    geometry.Point(9.450463499380801, 47.6649559172176),
    geometry.Point(9.450463614247271, 47.6649550512483),
    geometry.Point(9.450463463599689, 47.664954187754),
    geometry.Point(9.450463053866351, 47.6649533635807),
    geometry.Point(9.45046240253088, 47.6649526138965),
    geometry.Point(9.450461537386341, 47.6649519706911),
    geometry.Point(9.450460495349169, 47.6649514614106),
    geometry.Point(9.45040935260457, 47.6649360626301),
    geometry.Point(9.45036907619812, 47.664928709451),
    geometry.Point(9.447377834868041, 47.6644933952575),
    geometry.Point(9.447343269935271, 47.6644880343118),
    geometry.Point(9.44730847614896, 47.6644823034133),
    geometry.Point(9.44727413690042, 47.6644763151236),
    geometry.Point(9.444928887305879, 47.6640444576946),
    geometry.Point(9.444886220360861, 47.6640381906818),
    geometry.Point(9.444829205115131, 47.6640359557828),
    geometry.Point(9.4448279422305, 47.6640360849357),
    geometry.Point(9.44482674602855, 47.6640363876611),
    geometry.Point(9.44482566804831, 47.6640368509158),
    geometry.Point(9.444757321553571, 47.6640820372137)
]


area_p = geometry.Polygon(area)


buildings = ox.footprints_from_polygon(area_p)



buildings.loc[buildings.index == 557584181]['building']
```

> 557584181    office
> Name: building, dtype: object

```
print(area_p)
```

> POLYGON ((9.444757321553571 47.6640820372137, 9.44469147049122 47.6642370363376, 9.442746638836271 47.6675223477341, 9.44273323863089 47.6675486765942, 9.44272335456083 47.6675846924473, 9.44272337322715 47.6675856076278, 9.44272365679015 47.667586502615, 9.442724194246059 47.6675873426787, 9.442724964738851 47.6675880952201, 9.442725938369239 47.6675887310364, 9.442771524985689 47.6676085195463, 9.442809078141879 47.6676199425426, 9.443599054706221 47.6678292167847, 9.44364298889086 47.6678391758214, 9.44369319196211 47.6678454078942, 9.443694609235431 47.6678454056071, 9.44369600193242 47.6678452280573, 9.443697323077419 47.6678448812336, 9.443698528108349 47.6678443768344, 9.443744598701199 47.6678160313241, 9.443795360184319 47.6677784822092, 9.443991191770809 47.6676599114601, 9.44421793991903 47.667570002951, 9.44446657647225 47.667512336406, 9.44472720190474 47.6674892078198, 9.444989439424219 47.6675015380556, 9.445052589744799 47.6675088406224, 9.445117064489731 47.6675174206873, 9.445183601261711 47.6675274468952, 9.44523747329856 47.6675300193568, 9.445238809309229 47.6675299032106, 9.4452400852424 47.6675296113077, 9.445241251079061 47.667529155091, 9.445242261116221 47.6675285524453, 9.445243075758549 47.6675278269953, 9.44524366307046 47.6675270071801, 9.445257172339209 47.6674916444378, 9.44526138400154 47.6674643786881, 9.44526635876986 47.6674027181877, 9.44527842375639 47.6673216144847, 9.44528702520314 47.6672820624034, 9.445343690252869 47.6671237851091, 9.44544200701166 47.6669751340207, 9.445578690330031 47.6668410756375, 9.445606929899901 47.666818179473, 9.445637520256669 47.6667867600046, 9.445694232828229 47.6667392820943, 9.445718033000571 47.6667110812337, 9.445816550854619 47.6665782840333, 9.445885789521761 47.6664961432372, 9.44592142419992 47.6664586450851, 9.44609642847751 47.6663115101204, 9.446313359526091 47.6661926345661, 9.44656247099808 47.6661073591621, 9.4468325709589 47.6660595150674, 9.447111524661491 47.6660512517601, 9.44717730910928 47.6660540322315, 9.447316189895529 47.6660649297759, 9.44753610831893 47.6660902456686, 9.44758112940486 47.6660938580278, 9.44767071891042 47.6660918313842, 9.447684852061499 47.6660900296329, 9.44774691292624 47.6660795923001, 9.4479881800759 47.6660547725018, 9.448232085468209 47.6660604809193, 9.448470258112661 47.6660965216365, 9.448560914386359 47.6661163562617, 9.44857404167368 47.6661182063231, 9.448691583060739 47.6661430580836, 9.44873711713312 47.6661476818212, 9.44936429835351 47.6661892570172, 9.44940607834077 47.66619064719, 9.44946122599818 47.6661870380657, 9.449463401923399 47.6661858503929, 9.449498075077059 47.6661578721339, 9.449520006942709 47.6661337837734, 9.45042894326825 47.6650175089795, 9.45044714891934 47.6649921250378, 9.450463499380801 47.6649559172176, 9.450463614247271 47.6649550512483, 9.450463463599689 47.664954187754, 9.450463053866351 47.6649533635807, 9.45046240253088 47.6649526138965, 9.450461537386341 47.6649519706911, 9.450460495349169 47.6649514614106, 9.45040935260457 47.6649360626301, 9.45036907619812 47.664928709451, 9.447377834868041 47.6644933952575, 9.447343269935271 47.6644880343118, 9.44730847614896 47.6644823034133, 9.44727413690042 47.6644763151236, 9.444928887305879 47.6640444576946, 9.444886220360861 47.6640381906818, 9.444829205115131 47.6640359557828, 9.4448279422305 47.6640360849357, 9.44482674602855 47.6640363876611, 9.44482566804831 47.6640368509158, 9.444757321553571 47.6640820372137))

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code snippet so we can see what OSMnx is generating given the exact way you're using it. OSMnx retrieves whatever OSM has, given your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cached response data, they will reflect whatever was on OSM at the time that you cached them. You can turn caching off with the `config` function. Here's a minimal reproducible code example.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=False)
point = (47.6654265, 9.4464618)
gdf = ox.geometries_from_point(point, tags={'building':True}, dist=500)
gdf.shape #(137, 38)
gdf.loc[gdf['osmid']==557584181, 'building'] #office
```

Everything works fine. Note that v0.9 is several years old at this point and this code example uses v1.0.